# VAPI on Kali Linux on VMWare

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to install Vapi for a lab, and I am getting this error. Installed docker and tried some pages to troubleshoot it. Don't work.

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
WARNING: The APP_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The PUSHER_APP_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building www
Sending build context to Docker daemon  74.49MB
Step 1/9 : FROM php:7.4-apache
 ---> 20a3732f422b
Step 2/9 : RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f44840befe91
Step 3/9 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y libzip-dev     && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && docker-php-ext-install zip
 ---> Running in 8a38439962a0
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'                                                           
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'                                                                     
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.                                                                                                          
Reading package lists...                                                                                                                                                                           
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package libzip-dev
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y libzip-dev     && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && docker-php-ext-install zip' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'www' failed to build : Build failed
```

Any ideas what's the issue and how can I install Vapi? :D

Comment: "Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'" -- check your internet connection

Comment: Or DNS settings

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this just because some might need it. Restart the docker service and make sure your DNS is `8.8.8.8`

To restart docker, use:

```
sudo service docker restart
```